# Creating Socket in Tomcat servlet - Permission denied (connect failed)

Tags: java, linux, sockets, tomcat, servlets

so i have the weird problem, that I am not able to create a Socket to my localhost address. I try to open a socket out of my tomcat servlet to 127.0.0.1:6001. Another Application is listening on this port. And other services are able to connect to this service. But in my tomcat servlet i always get Permission denied (connect failed), when i try to connect. Am i missing something?

### Specs:

- tomcat-7.0.76
- CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708
- java version "1.8.0_121"

### I have already tried:

#### Adding permissions in catalina.policy

- grant codeBase "file:${tomcat.home}/webapps/App" {
      permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:6000-6200", "accept,connect,listen";
      permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*","read";
  };

#### Setting parameter in SELinux

- setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This 'permission denied' comes from the operating system, not from the Java Security Manager, so providing the `SocketPermission` is irrelevant. The userID that Tomcat is running as doesn't have permission to connect to that port.

Comment: Hey EJP, jep i just figured it out. Becuase when i set SELinux in permissive mode, it works fine. So i have to figure how to configure SELinux. I'll let you know when i found a configuration.